# Convert a Python (3.5.2) File into an exe?

Tags: python, pygame, exe

is there any surefire way to convert a Python (3.5.2) File into an exe? I have seen Pyinstaller, py2exe and cx_Freeze. cx_Freeze does not have a Python 3.5 version, only 3.4 so it isnt compatible. Py2exe works only for Python 2 and while I had some success with Pyinstaller, it returned an error relating to 9130 WARNING: hidden import "pygame._view" not found! (the only one as I can see).

The exe. file was created but malfunctioned and stopped working.

Any advice?

Comment: http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html  Although the blurb only mentions up to 3.4, there is an msi for 3.5.  http://nuitka.net/pages/download.html.  Doc at:  http://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html

Comment: hmm that would require me to download python 2 and im worried that complications might arise... I have understood (?) that pygame._view is not found simply because it has been renamed as pygame.bufferproxy in the updated versions of pygame, is there anyway to indicate to pyinstaller in the command prompt that what it may be looking for is in here? 
such as : pyinstaller --???pygame.bufferproxy filename.py

Comment: Why would you need python 2?  Or were you replying to a different comment?

Comment: from the user manual as linked above, i saw 

"Python3, yes but Python2 compile time dependency
For Python3 you need a Python2, but only during the compile time only, and that is for S..."

sounds a bit complicated, I would try to avoid that as im relatively new

Answer (score -1):

I used py2exe to convert python 3 files to exe files. I haven't tested with version 3.5 but this website says that this version of py2exe works with any python 3 versions.

1. Download and install [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.2)
2. Navigate to your python folder.
3. Create new text file called setup.
4. Insert these commands:
   from distutils.core import setup
   import py2exe
   setup(console=['nameofyourpyfile.py'])
5. Close the text file and open cmd.
6. Navigate to your python folder using command cd.
7. Enter this command: python setup.txt py2exe
8. Press enter and your done navigate to folder called dist and find your exe file.
9. If it doesn't work install program called [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) and try again. If pywin32 doesn't help then let me know I will help you for sure :D

Comment: can i assume setup.txt is my python script and i just need to add:
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['nameofyourpyfile.py'])
to the top of my python script?

Must I execute python setup.txt py2exe at the python folder? What if i want to create it on my Desktop can i just change directory there? 

Sorry for the incessant questions, i am a newbie, thanks~

Comment: No you can't. Setup.txt and your python script need to be two differed files and they can't be just anywhere. Setup.txt and your python script need to be in your python folder usually at C:\Python 35. If you want your exe file stored in different folder then you just need to copy ALL files in dist folder and paste them. NB! Your exe can't work without all dist folder's files. If you want one compressed exe file then I can't help you with that sorry . Also sorry for my bad English I'm from Estonia.

Comment: your English is by no ways bad haha, I understand it totally. Ok, shall try when i get back home, a small thanks for the clarifications, and if it works then a big thanks ~